# Remove Duplicates from Output of a Oracle SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to remove duplicate rows from the below query.

```
     SELECT CONTACTS.ROWID as ROW_PASS,
            DUTY_ROTA.ROWID as ROW_PASS_ROTA,
            DUTY_ROTA.DUTY_DATE AS DUTY_DATE,
            DUTY_ROTA.DUTY_TYPE AS DUTY_TYPE,
            DUTY_ROTA.DUTY_OFFICER AS DUTY_OFFICER,
            DUTY_TYPES.DESCRIPTION AS DUTY_DESC,
            CONTACTS.SNAME AS FULLNAME,
            CONTACTS.MOBILE AS MOBILE_NO,
            CONTACTS.TELNO AS OFFICE_TEL 
         FROM DUTY_ROTA,
              DUTY_TYPES,
              CONTACTS 
         WHERE DUTY_DATE between SYSDATE-1 
               AND SYSDATE+18  
               AND DUTY_ROTA.DUTY_TYPE = DUTY_TYPES.DUTY_TYPE 
               AND duty_rota.DUTY_OFFICER = contacts.duty_id 
               AND SNAME IS NOT NULL
```

I have been trying to identify the duplicates in the below manner - (by taking count(*) and group by the columns)

I have tried something like below code snippet too, but not helping I am getting right parenthisis missing error

```
SELECT CONTACTS.SNAME AS FULLNAME,
CONTACTS.ROWID as ROW_ID_CONTACT,
DUTY_ROTA.ROWID as ROW_ID_ROTA,
DUTY_ROTA.DUTY_TYPE AS DUTY_TYPE,
DUTY_ROTA.DUTY_OFFICER AS DUTY_OFFICER,
DUTY_TYPES.DESCRIPTION AS DUTY_DESC,
CONTACTS.MOBILE AS MOBILE_NO,
CONTACTS.OFFICETEL AS OFFICE_TEL, 
       Row_number() 
         OVER ( 
           partition BY CONTACTS.SNAME AS FULLNAME,
CONTACTS.ROWID as ROW_ID_CONTACT,
DUTY_ROTA.ROWID as ROW_ID_ROTA,
DUTY_ROTA.DUTY_TYPE AS DUTY_TYPE,
DUTY_ROTA.DUTY_OFFICER AS DUTY_OFFICER,
DUTY_TYPES.DESCRIPTION AS DUTY_DESC,
CONTACTS.MOBILE AS MOBILE_NO,
CONTACTS.OFFICETEL AS OFFICE_TEL
           ) AS rn 
FROM   DUTY_ROTA,DUTY_TYPES,CONTACTS WHERE DUTY_DATE between SYSDATE and SYSDATE+300 and contacts.duty_id = duty_rota.duty_officer 
AND DUTY_ROTA.DUTY_TYPE = DUTY_TYPES.DUTY_TYPE AND SNAME IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: problem is it is not working, it is not fetching any count(*)>2 values although by eyeing through I can see duplicate columns

Answer (score 1):

use having clause as shown below, please remove rowid as well

```
SELECT count(*),DUTY_ROTA.DUTY_DATE AS DUTY_DATE,DUTY_ROTA.DUTY_TYPE AS DUTY_TYPE,DUTY_ROTA.DUTY_OFFICER AS DUTY_OFFICER,DUTY_TYPES.DESCRIPTION AS DUTY_DESC,CONTACTS.SNAME AS FULLNAME,CONTACTS.MOBILE AS MOBILE_NO,CONTACTS.TELNO AS OFFICE_TEL FROM DUTY_ROTA,DUTY_TYPES,CONTACTS WHERE DUTY_DATE between SYSDATE-1 and SYSDATE+18  AND DUTY_ROTA.DUTY_TYPE = DUTY_TYPES.DUTY_TYPE AND duty_rota.DUTY_OFFICER = contacts.duty_id and SNAME IS NOT NULL 
group by
 DUTY_ROTA.DUTY_DATE,
 DUTY_ROTA.DUTY_TYPE,
 DUTY_ROTA.DUTY_OFFICER,
 DUTY_TYPES.DESCRIPTION,
 CONTACTS.SNAME,
 CONTACTS.MOBILE,
 CONTACTS.TELNO
having count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 DELETE FROM table_name
 WHERE rowid NOT IN
                   ( 
                     SELECT MIN(rowid)
                     FROM table_name
                     GROUP BY column1, column2, column3...
                   ) ;
```

**OR**

```
 CREATE TABLE t2 AS SELECT DISTINCT * FROM t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, in Oracle ROWID will be unique for each row in the table, so your query will return one row for each row in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

> Try to use RowNumber

```
SELECT * FROM
  (
  SELECT
  CONTACTS.SNAME AS FULLNAME,
  CONTACTS.ROWID as ROW_ID_CONTACT,
  DUTY_ROTA.ROWID as ROW_ID_ROTA,
  DUTY_ROTA.DUTY_TYPE AS DUTY_TYPE,
  DUTY_ROTA.DUTY_OFFICER AS DUTY_OFFICER,
  DUTY_TYPES.DESCRIPTION AS DUTY_DESC,
  CONTACTS.MOBILE AS MOBILE_NO,
  CONTACTS.OFFICETEL AS OFFICE_TEL, 
  Row_number() OVER ( Partition BY CONTACTS.SNAME AS FULLNAME,
                    CONTACTS.ROWID as ROW_ID_CONTACT,
                    DUTY_ROTA.ROWID as ROW_ID_ROTA,
                    DUTY_ROTA.DUTY_TYPE AS DUTY_TYPE,
                    DUTY_ROTA.DUTY_OFFICER AS DUTY_OFFICER,
                    DUTY_TYPES.DESCRIPTION AS DUTY_DESC,
                    CONTACTS.MOBILE AS MOBILE_NO,
                    CONTACTS.OFFICETEL AS OFFICE_TEL
                    Order By DUTY_ROTA.ROWID
                    ) AS RN
  FROM DUTY_ROTA,DUTY_TYPES,CONTACTS WHERE DUTY_DATE between SYSDATE and SYSDATE+300     
  AND contacts.duty_id = duty_rota.duty_officer     
  AND DUTY_ROTA.DUTY_TYPE = DUTY_TYPES.DUTY_TYPE AND SNAME IS NOT NULL
 )
Where RN=1
```

[Refer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions156.htm#SQLRF51720)

Comment: Hi Vignesh,
Can you please help me - How can I go along with my query please. Use of RowNumber and partition by is new to me.

Comment: Hi @Subhamoy I have updated solution . Please check this and let me know the status